# cli R package progress bars not showing

Tags: r

If I create multiple {cli} progress bars in quick succession, only the first progress bar is shown. However, if I add a short sleep with `Sys.sleep(0.2)`, all progress bars are shown:

```r
options(cli.progress_show_after = 0)

fun <- function(step) {
  cli::cli_progress_bar(
    clear = FALSE
  )
  cli::cli_progress_update(inc = 0)
  cli::cli_progress_done()
}

fun_sleep <- function(step) {
  cli::cli_progress_bar(
    clear = FALSE
  )
  cli::cli_progress_update(inc = 0)
  cli::cli_progress_done()
  Sys.sleep(0.2)
}

purrr::walk(1:3, function(x) fun(x))

purrr::walk(1:3, function(x) fun_sleep(x))
```

How do I show all progress bars without needing to use `Sys.sleep(0.2)`?

**Update**

I opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/r-lib/cli/issues/599